# Why is my Cycles rendering grainy?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, noise-reduction

I think the picture speaks a thousand words:

[image]

Comment: More samples and using *indirect clamp* would help. Start with a value of around 10 and work down unti your happy with the results.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles

Comment: meybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42908/cycles-render-noisy-even-when-using-a-high-number-of-samples/42947#42947

Comment: I think words are better when we don't know much else about your project... or post a thousand images worth of settings for your scene. But If you want a single worthwhile answer please upload a file so others can help you find the problem... you an use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/