# I'm using a high number of samples. Why is my render coming out in low quality?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Can someone help me determine why my render is coming out in such low quality? I have Cycles up to 500 *Render Samples*, but I have no idea why it looks like it's only using one.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: could you detail the lights and materials you are using here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid noisy renders in Cycles?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles)

Comment: Does it look the same if you keep everything set as it is except render it with the CPU?

Comment: Here's the next piece of information we need in order to help answer your question: Render it with only **one** sample. Then render it with **100** samples, and post all three results (including the one you have now) here.

Comment: ...if you don't have enough rep to do that, post links in the comments and someone (or me) will edit your question to add the images.

Comment: Maybe, you should check under dimensions, Resolution. I suspect it is 25% or 50%. Make it 100% and render it again.

Comment: possible duplicate of: [cycles-render-noisy-even-when-using-a-high-number-of-samples](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42908/cycles-render-noisy-even-when-using-a-high-number-of-samples/42947#42947)

Comment: Oh, good catch @cegaton. I'd forgotten about render layer overrides.

Comment: @Matt I've complied a list of commonly asked questions (and solutions) here: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/frequenty-asked-questions-on-blender-stack-exchange?cb=1

Comment: EXCELLENT!!! >:-) *evil hand wringing*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have any number other than 0 on the render layers, then your rendering will be limited to that value.

[image].

Solutions (choose one):

1. Make the number of samples on the render layer, the number of samples you need.
2. Turn that number back to 0 so that the sampling is controlled by the overall render settings for the scene.
3. Turn the layer sampling settings to "ignore"

   [image]

See this post: [Cycles render, noisy even when using a high number of samples](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42908/cycles-render-noisy-even-when-using-a-high-number-of-samples/42947#42947)