# Python Script Cycles Samples setting not respected

Tags: python, animation, scripting

I have a script for rendering files, but I am not able to figure out how to set the samples per tile and have that value be used.

[image]

My script is:

```
import bpy

bpy.context.scene.cycles.samples = 50

bpy.context.scene.render.tile_x = 128
bpy.context.scene.render.tile_y = 128

bpy.context.user_preferences.system.compute_device_type = 'CUDA'
bpy.context.user_preferences.system.compute_device = 'CUDA_0'

bpy.context.scene.cycles.device = 'GPU'

bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.compression = 90
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.color_mode ='RGBA'
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format='PNG'

bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)
```

However, when it's rendering, I get 100 samples per tile, no matter what settings I have in the .blend file or in the script.

```
Fra:1 Mem:61.04M (0.00M, Peak 84.41M) | Time:00:06.95 | Remaining:00:10.82 | Mem:11.84M, Peak:35.21M | Scene, RenderLayer | Path Tracing Tile 53/135, Sample 0/100
Fra:1 Mem:60.47M (0.00M, Peak 84.41M) | Time:00:07.07 | Remaining:00:10.68 | Mem:11.28M, Peak:35.21M | Scene, RenderLayer | Path Tracing Tile 53/135, Sample 100/100
```

Comment: You could check if [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/53567/34236) solves your problem.

Comment: I just discovered that when I do render inside the Blender editor using the Cycles renderer, with both CPU and GPU devices, I can change the Settings > Samples > Render value to 30 or 200 or whatever. However, once I click "Render" or "Animation", it's changing back to 100.