# Getting low resolution render images

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, noise-reduction

When i am rendering my scene in 1920×1080 at 100℅, and with a sample value of 500, I am getting a low qulality image which got rendered in just 8 seconds. How can I fix this![image]

Comment: That is not low resolution, but not enough samples. 500 samples is not enough. try 2000 or more.

Comment: 500 samples in 8 seconds? Wow. Either those weren't render samples or you have really decent hardware

Comment: Also make sure that you are not using a lower number of samples in your render layers. That setting overrides all other values set in the render section. Read: [Cycles render, noisy even when using a high number of samples](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42908/cycles-render-noisy-even-when-using-a-high-number-of-samples/42947#42947)

Comment: My pc specs are 2GB ram, and internal intel graphics. And thats what i can't understand. Once it took me 2 hrs to render just one scene with 450 samples of 1080px

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53540/im-using-a-high-number-of-samples-why-is-my-render-coming-out-in-low-quality/53567#53567

Comment: Did it really take only 8 Seconds? Did you accidentally set your preview samples to 500 and have your render Samples at .. maybe 3 ?.. :D

Comment: that is not 500 samples. and no 500 will never render in 8 secs. Double check that you do not have a sample count overriding your 500.

Answer (score 0):

Recheck the samples and if they are 500 samples then you can enable denoising after going to 2 sphere icon which is second icon.