# The amount of samples in cycles render won't change

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a problem regarding the samples setting with cycles render on blender. Whenever I made changes to the amount of the samples I want in the samples setting it just won't save, it always revert back to 135, the amount of samples I used the first time I tinker with it. I want to use lesser amount of samples for preview purpose, and increase it to more than 135 but it simply won't save the setting. Sorry if it's a bit long, How do I save the samples setting?. I really appreciate all the answers.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings. On what part of the interface are you setting the number of samples? Are you changing for preview or render? Or did you set a value for the render layer's sampling? Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53540/im-using-a-high-number-of-samples-why-is-my-render-coming-out-in-low-quality/53567#53567

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I set the number of samples on the render setting interface. I've also tried doing what is suggested on the reference and the render got stuck at 2/Samples set.

Comment: It's hard to help you if we cannot understand the problem... what do you mean by "render got stuck at 2/Samples set? Please edit your question and add images of your current settings.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think is that you must have a keyframe on your render samples. I would try to right click and remove keyframes.

[image]

Comment: I right clicked on the samples render box and there's no option to remove keyframes, I saw insert keyframe instead. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: if you want to add your blend file I can take a look and figure it out for you. http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/