# Render is incredibly Grainy!

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm new to blender and I started last week. I'm now having trouble with the final results of my render, it looks incredibly grainy.
[image]

What I have tried so far is that I changed the resolution to 100% , samples to 500, tried using the 'area light' and i enabled 'multiple importance'.

Here's the link to my Blender file: [image]

UPDATE

I can't find the AA settings:

[image]

Update:
When I try to render my animation it comes out as nothing.
[image]

It also says this:

[image]

Comment: Please do not add more questions to the original post. New questions should be asked as a new post.

Answer (score 6):

Probable causes of noisy renders:
(click on the links in blue)

- [Render Samples set too low](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles) 100 samples might just be too low for what you want, try a higher value.

  Here's the scene at 800 samples:

  [image]
- [Samples set on render layer override regular sample settings](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42947/1853).
- [Lights or environment not set to multiple importance](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5309/when-should-mis-be-used-and-when-should-it-be-disabled/5397#5397). Aditionally [this link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8152/what-is-multiple-importance-sample-option/8156#8156)
- [render resolution is set to less than 100%](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/rendered-image-looks-pixelated)
- Use [branched path tracing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/what-is-branched-path-tracing-and-how-is-it-useful) instead of the default samples

  [image]

  Bring up the AA samples and then set the values for each type of sample according to the materials in your scene. Note that each of this values is multiplied by that of the AA Samples. (for example 4 diffuse will turn into 500 samples when the AA value is set to 125)

Comment: I tried all of these steps and it still look grainy

Comment: Your images show that you are rendering at 50% resolution.

Comment: I now changed my resolution to 200%. Should i be going further?

Comment: No resolution should be 100 percent (unless you want to downsample after) Please edit your question and detail what you have tried and update the images with your current settings. A faster way to help you is if you upload your file for inspection. Use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and edit the link into your original post.

Comment: Alrighty, im done. I was unable to add more pictures because I needed more experience.

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Hi, I switched to Branched Path tracing but I was not able to see any AA samples.

Comment: look at the second image on the answer, underlined in yellow...

Comment: @JeffTeoh add the images into your post, not on the answer.

Comment: I can't add more than 2 images in my question post. Apologies, I accidentally added the image in the answer.

Comment: I'm so sorry for any inconvenience I have caused.

Comment: @JeffTeoh No problem. I do not understand why your interface does not change to branched path tracing correctly. Try unistalling and installing blender again. In any case what you need are more samples. If this is intended for animation don't stress over noise so much. Keep in mind that in animation each frame is displayed for a very short time.

Comment: Hi, I reinstalled Blender and I'm still unable to see AA sample. Also, when I tried rendering it, it comes out blank. I really need to figure out how to get the AA samples as I tried to render the animation on 5000 render samples and looks the same.

Comment: I tried to increase the samples render to 1000 and it did not help at all.. It still look the same.