# Light not going through the glass in the window

Tags: lighting

[image]

I am having a problem with lighting my room with the sun.  I don't think its a problem with my window but just in case I put the node group. No matter how much strength I put on it doesn't light up the room.As long as the room has a ceiling, even if I put the sun in the middle of the room, it will not light up. When I turn off cast shadow however the room lights but I know it is not the way lighting is intended. I am fairly new to blender .

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles) and  [How can I make a more realistic glass shader?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/how-can-i-make-a-more-realistic-glass-shader)

Comment: Have you tried adding a [Light Portal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33877/47253) to your window? ... helps bringing down the sampels you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options.

1. Let the room Recieve Transperent
2. Use Cycles render
3. Let the Sun light cast no shadows

I believe the first one is most helpful.

**1. Let the room Recieve Transperent**

Change the material applied to the room. (Not the window)

If you scroll down, you can find the [Shadow](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/materials/properties/shadows.html#shadow-receiving-object-material) panel. Tick the Recieve transperent.

This works with the default blender render.

**2. Use Cycles render**

Cycles is a physic based render and let the light penetrate through the window.
For links, check the comment on the question.

**3. Let the Sun light cast no shadows**

I believe this is not your required solution but just in case this was.
The ray will IGNORE the ceiling.

Go to the light setting of the sunlight and Switch from Ray shadow to No shadow. (at the Shadow panel)

**What I think is best**

Combining 1 and 3 might be a neat solution.
Make two sunlights and let one light ray shadows, the other, none. This will lighten up the entire room while especially lighting up the wall on the opposite side of the window.

[image: Yellow window]

Comment: The OP using Cycles.

Comment: How could have I mistaken !? Should I remove this answer or leave it here?
 I mean, I never found a stack exchange answer for blender render and I believe this answer is worthy for some other people. (Should I ask and answer a QA my self?)

Comment: im sorry but they didnt help much

Comment: i dontknow if this helps but even when i put the sun inside the room it dosent work, however when i use any other lamps they work fine