# wHow do i make the the sun lamp light pass throught this window?

Tags: light

How do i make this spot lamp light go through this window? -[image]The window in the wall is just a hole in a plane with some meshes in front of it.
Sorry for my bad english.

My sun lamp is pointed at the window like this:

[image]

Comment: If you want a spot light... then change to a spot light (not sun) and position it so that it is aiming at the window... If you are using a glass shader on the window read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/how-can-i-make-a-more-realistic-glass-shader

Comment: You may also be interested in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33017/what-does-light-portal-mean/33877#33877

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply rotate the sun lamp until it's at the correct angle, so the light will come through. If you are using a spot lamp, make sure the lamp is outside of the window.