# Bathroom Lit only from the Window - Too Dark

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, lighting

So my idea was to build a bathroom that is lit only by its window, so I put it together and tried it out, but it didn't come out as I was expecting to, of course I'm a newbie at blender so I thought I ask for some help with it. The result was a too dark scene, besides some light leaking from the walls but that may be simpler to solve, my biggest problem is the very dark room.

I tried increasing the emission strength of the Sun Light I put outside, tried 1, then 14, then 50 just to see how it would be, the render image bellow is with the strength set to 50.

I tried turning off the visibility of the window's glass, it did improve a tiny little bit, but almost not noticeable.

I'm using cycles, the images bellow show the result I got, the solid mode view, outside the bathroom, the node scheme of the sun light I'm using and the node scheme of the glass texture it is used in the window glass.

[image: I'm using Cycles to render, and this was the result I got]

[image: This is the Solid Mode view so you can have an idea]

[image: That is outside the bathroom, I created the area in the back so the light wouldn't enter from another place but the window.]

[image: That is the node scheme of the sun light]

[image: Node scheme of the window glass texture]

Comment: Have you set up a portal at the window? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33017/what-does-light-portal-mean/33877#33877

Comment: Also make sure you have enough bounces in the Diffuse and Specular Rays. Since most of your light will be indirect (bouncing of walls, etc.), setting this amount low here will result in a very dark scene.