# why my indoor scene is so noisy?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, noise-reduction, denoise

[image: Cycles rendered]

yeah i know that the  sample rate is low, i increased it to 300 and it still was noisy, i think it has something to do with the indirect light, right?

I dont know if i need to give more info, im quite new to blender, like, a week new.

The project file is here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RKYw3Yn7-31cWtKL_Wtp0Tn32uMfnLJi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid noisy renders in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles)

Comment: Can you include the blend file as well so we can have a look?

Comment: Hello :). Just to add.. using 1000 - 1500 samples is nothing unusual for final renders. Indoor scenes can *easily* go to 3000 samples for good results.

Comment: Try adding a light portal in place of your window : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33017/what-does-light-portal-mean

Comment: @Ashok yeah, sure.

Comment: @Gorgious i tried that but i might have configured it wrong, ill try again then.

Comment: @bstnhnsl not really, i mean, adding samples is quite an obvious fix but my computer is slooooow, so i wanted another way to fix it, but so far, it seems im out of options.

Comment: @JachymMichal i did that and it looked way better, but its reaaaly slow. i think im just not used to complicated renders, thanks though!

Comment: @ThomasBouasli In that case, perhaps [BlenderGuru can help](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-cycles) with faster renders :).

Comment: @JachymMichal Binge watching all his tutorials for a week now XD, Thanks, i will take a look.